# ExecuteReader commandtext property has not been initialized when click buy button and the quantity is not subtracted

Tags: c#, sql-server

The `PQuantity` and `Qty` columns are from two tables. How to subtract two quantity from different table?

```
protected void btnBuyNow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string id = Session["UserID"].ToString();

    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Int32 myQty = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["Qty"].ToString());

            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE tblProducts SET PQuantity=PQuantity-" + myQty + " WHERE id=" + id;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Response.Redirect("OrderConfirmation.aspx");
        }
    } 

    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Learn to use SQL Parameters to avoid SQL Injection and formatting errors.

Comment: This causes the exception:

`sda.Fill(dt);`
Because you have assigned a `SqlCommand` which has no `CommandText` for the adaper's `SelectCommand` at this time.

Comment: The SqlDataAdapter's [UpdateCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.updatecommand) documentation does an example to show you how to setup update commands. Even with parameters.

Comment: You have some serious issues with your code: Lack of parameterization. Not disposing connection and command/adapter objects. Adapter has no `select` query. `ToString` on an `int` only to convert it back again is pointless, just cast it: `(int)`. You don't actually need an adapter, `select` query and datatable here at all, just use a joined update, and check the RowsAffected.